# Remove generated PDF from local machine after it has been closed

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, io

I have an abstract question:
I have a WPF application, in which one of the modules generates PDF files, based on the original document (stored on FTP).
The generated file is saved on the local machine to a directory generated with GetTemporaryDirectory().
What I want to achieve, is delete the temp file after the user have closed the PDF Reader (which is not a part of my application), so the app wont leave any trash behind.
So far I thought about several solutions, but none of them fits well:
1. Read PDF directly from MemoryStream, as I understood - it is impossible, since a file generation is required to open it.
2. Set the hardcoded file name and directory path. But this is a poor solution, which still leaves trash, only less. Even if I will "generate additional file, if original is inaccessible" (e.x. file is currently opened).
3. Open the PDF in a new window of my application (embed PDF reader into application). But its an ugly and overkilling solution
4. Add a new column to my Document object table ... I don`t even want to think where this solution will lead to. But it is here, since it is one of possible solutions.

Will highly appreciate any related ideas.
Thank you in advance.
**Solution:**
Whenever I am generating a new temporary PDF - a am adding its full file path (string) to an AppSession dictionary object, which is a string array, lets call "generated_files".
Then I am putting an event handler to closing of the application window ().
that event is trying to delete each generated_file from generated_files. If attempt is unsuccessful - add this file to string array inaccessible_files (opened by user or used by other process at this exact moment).
At the end, serialize the inaccessible_files.
On the next launch of the application - we desirialize inaccessible_files and setting them as generated_files, so they will be cleaned on the next finalization of the session.
I have omitted details since the question was abstract, but the logic like this and works good enough (its not the perfect solution, but it is way, waaay better than common practice of opening pdf with IE). As well - it is a good starting point for generating a cleaner algorithm.
Cheers.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer because it doesn't solve what you're asking: I've done this before, but I open my file inside my application through a web browser component (you can use the one that comes with WPF).

Comment: @RodrigoVedovato Agree with that, it is an option, but fits under #3. But eventually, if I wont get with anything better - I will take one of them. Thank you.

Comment: @RodrigoVedovato see my updated question with solution. I gave a try to webbrowser implementation, but it was just killing the whole UX.